# What is in the file John Smith shows to Himmler, and how did he get it?

Tags: the-man-in-the-high-castle

In S02E10 of *The Man in the High Castle*, Smith asks Raeder to dig up the intelligence files on... someone. Later he shows the file to Himmler,

> which proves that Heydrich and Heusmann conspired to assassinate Hitler. Himmler is sufficiently convinced that he orders the arrest of Acting Chancellor Heusmann.

While Smith already knew this fact from a previous episode, the file must have contained some extraordinarily convincing corroborating evidence in order to have achieved this outcome: something that couldn't be easily faked. What was this evidence and how did Smith obtain it?

Comment: IMO, it’s because Smith, as we see throughout the show, is VERY resourceful. Layers upon layers resourceful. It’s how he got to where he was after the Nazi victory in America. So it would serve to prove he can dig up the goods on just about anyone he wants to, no matter how high up the chain they are and no matter how much they think they trust him (which is what he wants). He likely had a plan for just about everyone who could threaten him and his family. A simple spy job, photographs or stolen files, maybe an intercepted letter, and such. Likely enough to ensure Himmler’s support.

Comment: You answered the question yourself: he asked Raeder to dig it up. Supposedly Raedler didn't do it alone, he must have, as MissouriSpartan mentioned, contacted several different people to do collect different forms of evidence for him.

Comment: The only file John shows to Himmler is Reinhard's connection to Heusmann. Are you asking about the file proved Heusmann as a traitor